# Overriding layouts from your module

Tags: overrides, joomla-3.6, form

I have already copied the `renderfield.php` and `renderlabel.php` files from `~/layouts/joomla/form/` to `~/modules/mod_mymodule/layouts/joomla/form` but the overrides don't seem to be recognised.

I have taken info from [here](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Sharing_layouts_across_views_or_extensions_with_JLayout), but what am I missing?

I have tried switching my template (latest Helix3 template) to Protostar, but the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override anything from your template the override needs to be in the templates `/html` directory. In this case your override should be at:

```
YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/layouts/joomla/form/
```

Comment: I was just hoping there was a way to do this straight from my module, without having to override for the whole template. I find it weird that this behaviour is allowed for components, but not modules?

Comment: If my answer helped then perhaps you can mark it as correct?